# Entity Framework for Authentication / Authorization

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, authentication

In the past, we just used the default asp.net configuration to automatically add tables and related codes. Then update it a little bit to fit our needs, such as some custom profile provider.

Now we are using MVC3 and Entity Framework 4. In addition, we are using MySQL as the database this time since EF4 communicates well with all types of databases. Then we have some problems.

1. The asp.net configuration will create a separate connection string entry in web.config and use that one. Is it possible we can use our existing EDMX model?
2. Since it is impossible for us to write stored procedure in MySQL database, is there any example code that designed those membership/profile providers without using stored procedures?

Thank you.

---

[Update - in response to Mathieu Leblanc]

My current project is to use an existing MySQL database, which already contains the membership, roles and profiles information. Therefore, we are not to use `Aspnet_regsql.exe` to create new tables into the database. How can we use the existing database structure to design those providers?

I have not yet thought of a good solution so far. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use a single database to hold Authentication tables and your regular, EF4 database.

You can generate the script that creates all the ASP.Net authentication tables with the command-line tool Aspnet_regsql.exe (details here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx)

You can also modify your web.config to have a single Connection String to point to your single database, but I suggest you keep two lines, each having their name (and their purpose), and simply have them point to the same database.

It's gonna look like

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS2008;Integrated Security=SSPI;initial catalog=MyDatabase" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS2008;Integrated Security=SSPI;initial catalog=MyDatabase" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
...
```

For your question on how to deal with MySQL with ASP.Net authentication database, in regards to Stored Proc, I have no idea how (and if) this works.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But there are some limitations to your proposed solution. There are already users and roles and profiles information in the tables of the MySQL database. How can we build provider that use those existing tables instead of creating new ones? 

I have updated the question.

Comment: Maybe I understood your question upside down?  You already have the membership database.  Does it work?

Comment: The membership database is a MySQL. I am trying to use those user data stored in its tables.